# Angular.js - Render tab index once view has formed with any templates / Directives

Tags: angularjs, accessibility, tabindex

Does anyone have a solution to dynamically defining tab index's with Angular.js?

I'm using UI router with 2 views (Menu/Main view) and drop down directive in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Accessibility's first rule of tabindexes - don't use any value except 0 or -1. The reason for this is that positive tabindexes cause accessibility problems with, in some instances, items that should be easy to access becoming very tedious or difficult to access.

Given this rule, why would you want to set the tabindexes after render?

Comment: Thanks, to answer your question from your feedback I would not need to incrementally number the indexes. I may need to do some work on Angulars side with how directives work in the page, which seem to change the order (in a non linear) way when all are set to 0 which would make the experience on a keyboard a bit annoying.

Comment: The keyboard order *should* be the same order as the HTML DOM. If it seems weird it could be due to CSS positioning. If you create a jsfiddle, I could take a look.

Comment: I'll put a jsfiddle togther when I have time over the weekend or Monday. I saw on your profile that you're interested in Angular/mongo (I'd recommend this book I read, http://www.amazon.com/Write-Modern-Apps-MEAN-Stack/dp/0133930157). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I started to build a plunkr but the project I'm working on is far to complicated to build inside this kind of these type of tools. I managed to remove all the  tab indexes from the project (apart from one instance), and corrected a few divs to buttons - Which solved 90% of the problem. There was also some work with keyboard events, ensuring custom drop downs can open/close/select items etc.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/6Nwwz7uwsrJavIWaWbC3?p=preview - This may help give some insight into how I have got the drop down to work. The div element has -1 to stop focus occurring on this element - where the button now receives focus on tab and opens out. Using event.keyCode, I track the enter press to make the selection / toggle the drop down (when no item is selected).

Comment: JavaScript is missing

Comment: I'll add this soon, there are a few more advanced things I'm doing with it to have arrow key functionality also. I'll try and build out the page into Plunkr, so you can see the whole process. Thanks, Nick.